# How to properly activate an MVC View in Sencha Touch V2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm running Sencha Touch V2 beta and I'm looking at the most [recent documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/).

I've followed the `Ext.application` instructions and am trying to properly lay out my MVC application. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to actually load up a View with this approach.

**index.js**

```
Ext.application({

    name: 'rpc',
    defaultUrl: 'home/index',
    controllers: ['home'], //note: define controllers here
    launch: function () {

        console.log('Ext.application ~ launch'),

        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            id: 'rpc-rootPanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.viewport.Viewport', {
            id:'rpc-rootPanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide'
        });

    }
});
```

**homeController.js**

```
Ext.define('rpc.controller.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['home.index'],
    stores: [],
    refs: [],
    init: function () {
        console.log('rpc.controller.home ~ init');
    },

    index: function () {
        console.log('rpc.controller.home ~ index');
    }
});
```

**indexView.js**

```
Ext.define('rpc.view.home.index', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    id: 'rpc-view-home-index',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Videos',
            handler: function () {
            }
        }],
        html:'test'
    }
});
```

Any help you might be able to offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new release follows MVC concepts introduced in ExtJS 4. You should read [Architecture guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture) because Sencha Touch will be following the same arch.Here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure for Sencha Touch 2 application]

During development of your application, you should make use of sencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js in your html. This helps in debugging your application.

Here is the application class:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.application({
    name: 'rpc',
    appFolder: 'app',           
    controllers: ['Home'],
    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            fullscreen: true,           
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items:[{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />'
            },{
                title: 'Compose',
                iconCls: 'compose',
                xtype: 'homepage'
            }]          
        });     
    }
});
```

Note, how I have included the homepage view using the alias (xtype: 'homepage').

Here is the controller:

```
Ext.define('rpc.controller.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['home.HomePage'],
    init: function() {    

        console.log('Home controller init method...');
    }    
});
```

And finally, my Homepage view:

```
Ext.define('rpc.view.home.HomePage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',    
    alias: 'widget.homepage',
    config: {               
        html: '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("InitComponent for homepage");      
        this.callParent();  
    }       
});
```

The alias property is used to instantiate instance of the class when needed. You could also use the Ext.create method.

I hope this will help you get started with Sencha Touch.

Comment: This is good, seems like the alias bit is what did it... am I right?

Comment: can you explain what the 'widget' is referring to?

Comment: What if you are using a specific file structure? IE: Your user visits http://mysite.com/app/ but the actual files are located in http://mysite.com/plugin/senchatouch/app/. Is there anyway to rewrite where the views are found?

Comment: @Tom, Refer the doc: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath .. you should be able to specify your folder location

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Abdel.

You can also do it though profiles, as demonstrated in this answer:
[Sencha Touch 2.0 MVC tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229849/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-tutorial/9247251#9247251)