# How to put a button in Sencha Touch 2.0 via MVC using a view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've tried the simple MVC example like this [How to properly activate an MVC View in Sencha Touch V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815905/how-to-properly-activate-an-mvc-view-in-sencha-touch-v2) .
It's ok, but let's say i want to add a button in the panel using a view.

I've tried to do following..

app.js :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.application({
    name: 'rpc',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Home'],
    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            fullscreen: true,     
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items:[{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />'
            },{
                title: 'Compose',
                iconCls: 'compose',
                xtype: 'mybutton'
            }]          
        });     
    }
});
```

control

```
    Ext.define('rpc.controller.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['home.Button'],
    init: function() {    

        console.log('Home controller init method...');
    }
});
```

view

```
    Ext.define('rpc.view.home.Button', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',    
    alias: 'widget.mybutton',
    initialize: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls  : 'demobtn',
            flex : 1
            }]
        ;

        this.callParent();  
    }
});
```

The result i receive is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Where is the error? What is the right way to add the button using a view with MVC in Sencha Touch 2.0 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the way you define your rpc.view.home.Button view, I don't call initialize() in my views, I just do:

```
Ext.define('rpc.view.home.Button', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'mybutton',
config: {
    items = [
        {
        xtype: 'button',
        cls  : 'demobtn',
        flex : 1
        }
    ]    
}
});
```