# Dyanamically tab content adding issue

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

Here my code in sencha. im having a 4 tabs When click button action in any tab content the new view as has been added in tab bar dynamically.here my code

```
var wishlist = {
            standardSubmit : false,
            items: [
                    {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    scope:this,
                    defaults: {
                    required: true,
                    labelAlign: 'left',
                    },
                    title: 'hom',
                    items: [                              
                            {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'password',
                            label: 'Category',
                            useClearIcon: true
                            },{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'password',
                            label: 'Location',
                            useClearIcon: true
                            }],
                     },
                     {
                             xtype:  'button',
                             text:   'Add Wish',
                             ui:     'confirm',
                             handler: function()
                             {
                            //Here when i click other view has been added in tab bar
                            view.setActiveItem(0, {type:'fade', direction:'left'});
                            view.setActiveItem({
                                       title: 'Add Wish',
                                       items: [wishlist]
                                       });

                     });
                      },
                    }]
            };
```

Tab bar integeration code here

```
  var view = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
                       fullscreen: false,
                       tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
                       items: [{
                               title: 'HOME',
                               iconCls: 'home',
                               items: [{
                                       xtype: 'toolbar',
                                       title: 'My Items',
                                       },wishlist]

                               },
                               {
                               title: 'ITEMS',
                               iconCls: 'star',
                               items: [{
                                       xtype: 'toolbar',
                                       title: 'Add Items',
                                       },signinformBase]
                               },
                               {
                               title: 'PROFILE',
                               iconCls: 'user',
                               items: [{
                                       xtype: 'toolbar',
                                       title: 'MY PROFILE',
                                       },wishlist]
                               },{
                               title: 'FRIENDS',
                               iconCls: 'team',
                               items: [{
                                       xtype: 'toolbar',
                                       title: 'FRIENDS',
                                       },wishlist]
                               },

                       });
```

Please help me to sort out

Comment: Your need to explain what you want to do with above code.

Comment: Whenever i click any tab the view is coming by adding as other tab... i want to show the view in same tab pressed

Comment: Do you following MVC ?

Comment: yeah...can you mention some refrence link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video) and start building some simple application.

Learn [Sencha Class System](https://vimeo.com/33437222)

In sencha framework folder there is a examples folder you can find many examples there, use that to start leaning and experiment with it.

Then, You need to know some more specific concepts like Store and MVC Pattern

If you are not familiar with MVC then

[MVC in Depth Part 1](https://vimeo.com/33311074)

[MVC in Depth Part 2](https://vimeo.com/33430731)

[Useful SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229849/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-tutorial)